# Hosting only a subdomain in Azure dns service

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, azure-dns

We have a "traditional" dns service, where some outsourcing company manages our dns services. We host a lot of services in the cloud (mostly Azure) and then must submit tickets to the dns guys to create cname -registrations (and sometimes also txt records for domain ownership validation) pointing to the services.

E.g. a web service in Azure could be at the address ourapplication.azurewebsites.net and today we would create a cname such as ourapplication.ourcompany.com pointing to that.

A lot of these services could very well be hosted in a subdomain such as ourapplication.**app**.ourcompany.com.

In Azure there is service called Dns Zone, which to my understanding is a full dns service. Can we keep our current dns setup for the main ourcompany.com domain but have dns services for *.app.ourcompany.com in Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You always can delegate your sub-domain to a different set of nameservers using NS DNS resource records.

See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/27134/how-exactly-should-i-set-up-dns-to-delegate-authority-for-subdomains) for details.